# Swift - optional dates comparison

Tags: ios, swift, date, core-data

I'm trying to implement code in swift which will give me the closest date from current date.

The thing is I want users to choose in maximum 3 dates, and every time he chooses the date is added to the array named "reminders"

Then I check how many items (max 3) are in this array (named: reminders), and store the particular date/ dates from the array using CoreData:

```
if addObjectView.reminders.count == 1 {
            newobject.firstReminder = addObjectView.reminders[0]
        }
        if addObjecteView.reminders.count == 2 {
            newobject.firstReminder = addObjectView.reminders[0]
            newobject.secondReminder = addObjectView.reminders[1]

        }
        if addObjectView.reminders.count == 3 {
            newobject.firstReminder = addObjectView.reminders[0]
            newobject.secondReminder = addObjectView.reminders[1]
            newobject.thirdReminder = addObjectView.reminders[2]
        }
```

Then I want to implement code to check first if the first/second/thirdReminder from CoreData is nil, and if it's not then compare it to current date. If it is 'larger' then set String from this date as label. But I want also to compare date from first/second/thirdReminder between themselves or somehow make sure that the firstReminder will always be earlier than second and so on.

I don't know if it is that hard, but I'm trying to figure it out and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`nil coalescing operator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) for this purpose.

> The nil coalescing operator `(a ?? b)` unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if `a` is nil. The expression `a` is always of an optional type. The expression `b` must match the type that is stored inside `a`.
>
> [<sub>**Source - developer.apple.com**</sub>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

You could get the reminder's date, stored in `myOptionalDate`, and check if it is nil. If it is, then we will do

```
0 > NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

which will always be false. If it isn't nil, we can do the equivalent of

```
myOptionalDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 > NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

which will tell you if you if the label should be added

```
if((myOptionalDate?.timeIntervalSince1970 ?? 0) > NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970){
    //add the label
}
```

Which is shorthand for

```
var myInterval = 0
if(myOptionalDate != nil){
    myInterval = myOptionalDate!.timeIntervalSince1970
}

if(myInterval > NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Also, although this doesn't have to do with the question, depending on how your code is formatted, you shouldn't have to use if statements to check how many reminders there are

By default, `newobject.firstReminder`, `newobject.secondReminder`, and `newobject.thirdReminder` will (I'm assuming) be nil. So, you could just change all of your example code to

```
let originalReminders = addObjectView.reminders
newobject.firstReminder = originalReminders.count > 0 ? originalReminders[0] : nil
newobject.secondReminder = originalReminders.count > 1 ? originalReminders[1] : nil
newobject.thirdReminder = originalReminders.count > 2 ? originalReminders[2] : nil
```

if the default value isn't nil, you could simply replace `nil` in the above code with your default value

Comment: Perfect idea with the use of NSTimeIntervalSince1970! Thanks!